# Foreign key in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, indexing

Can someone help me to understand how to use foreign key in MySQL Query?
Let's say I have 2 tables

```
table VinDatabase
+-------+----------+------------+
| case_id| car_model|    vin    |
+-------+----------+------------+
|  1     |    VW    |  ABCDEFG  |
+-------+----------+------------+
|  2     |    VW    |  GFEDCBA  |     
+-------+----------+------------+
table cases
+-------+----------+------------+
|case_id|   date   |    price   |
+-------+----------+------------+
|   1   |08.04.2015|    11000   |
+-------+----------+------------+
|   2   |02.03.2015|     7000   |
+-------+----------+------------+
```

With INDEX: VIN in VinDatabase table and case_id in cases table

Because on my site users always search just by VIN number, how query can look to get to DATE for example?

Right now my query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM VinDatabase WHERE vin = :vin
```

from where I get case_id and after that make new query:

```
SELECT * FROM cases WHERE case_id = :case_id
```

Is there some better way how to do it?
Also how query will looks like if VIN / case_id are not uniqe?

**EDIT:**
How it works from proces site:

1. User come on page and add VIN to input ( let's say ABCDEFG )
2. Server take VIN and need to find case_id in VINDatabase table
3. With case_id it go to search to cases table.
4. Output from both, VinDatabase and cases table

Comment: The second query I gave in my answer solves your problem.  You should review the basics of relational databases before you proceed any further with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `JOIN` on the two tables like this:

```
SELECT * FROM vinDatabase v INNER JOIN cases c
ON v.case_id = c.case_id
WHERE v.vin = 'ABCDEFG' AND c.case_id = 1
```

**Output**:

```
+--------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
| case_id| car_model|    vin     |   date   |    price   |
+--------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
|   1    |    VW    |  ABCDEFG   |08.04.2015|    11000   |
+--------+----------+------------+----------+------------+
```

**Update**:

In the event that multiple records exist for just a single given VIN number, you would have to modify the query to get back a single result.  To get the most recent single entry for a given VIN number (with potentially multiple cases) you could use:

```
SELECT * FROM vinDatabase v INNER JOIN cases c
ON v.case_id = c.case_id
WHERE v.vin = 'ABCDEFG'
ORDER BY c.date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thumb up for your answer, but may I ask how it is if case_id is not UNIQE?

Comment: If multiple records exist for a given VIN and case number, then you would get multiple records back.  If you update your question with more requirements, I can update the query.

Comment: question edited, also marking your answer as correct :)

Comment: Just notice, this question is joining 2 SELECT but not helping when this should be QUERY when you know just VIN and not case_id

Comment: Tim, I really appreciate your help, but in query you adding say case_id=1 which I dont know when i start query.
User come on my site and just give me VIN, I need to get that case_id from table